# What do the number of hops in traceroute show?

Tags: ping, traceroute

I carried out the tracert command on two different websites hosted in two different locations. I tried it on a website hosted in the UK which is where im located and also a website thats located in poland. Im confused as to why more hops were required for the uk based website when my ping to the uk based website is much lower.

Comment: Each ISP builds their network in a different way. However, questions about networks not under your control are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracert will tell you how many routers traffic needs to traverse in order to get to the target destination. Traceroute sends packets with TTL values that gradually increase from packet to packet, starting with a TTL value of one. Routers decrement TTL values of packets by one when routing and discard packets whose TTL value has reached zero, returning the ICMP error message ICMP Time Exceeded.
As to why it takes more hops to get to a physically closer destination, that has to do with the internet infrastructure and available routes to the destination.

Comment: "_Tracert will tell you how many routers traffic needs to traverse in order to get to the target destination._" Actually tracert only tells you how many routers that tracert, itself, needs to traverse. Tracert uses ICMP, and some ISPs look for route tracing, either by ICMP, low TTL number, or something else, and will reroute such traffic. Tracert cannot be relied upon to determine the path of TCP, UDP, or other protocols.